# WPF C# MouseEnter event does not work at first

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control that contains a canvas and in that canvas I draw some rectangles and I defined the MouseEnter event for each rectangle.
But these events do not work at first I run the program.
At first some of them work and some not but after some time all work correctly.
I can not put the code here but I will be thankful for any help!

Comment: Sorry to say that, but if you can't put the code here, you're in the wrong place to ask. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ok thank you very much to the advice !

Answer (score 0):

for people with the same problem:
it solved and it was because when you draw something you should fill it to have the mouse events working good : just fill it with brushes.transparent
if you do not set the fill property the mouse events will not work properly